# Why does Access recalculate a stored query when I copy it? Can I tell it not to?

Tags: query, ms-access

When I copy and paste a stored query in Access, it's usually because (a) I want to back up the code before making changes, or (b) I want to make a new query by making changes to that one. All I want is to replicate the SQL of the query with a new name.

But when I copy the query to the clipboard, Access runs it, and I can't paste it until that finishes. This is a nuisance if the query is large and takes a long time to run.

Why does Access do that? Is there a way to tell it not to, and to just give me a copy of the code with a new name?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found out why it works that way, but I have found out how to get around it, and it's really simple.

The copy/paste process I was talking about in the question is in the object list on the left side of the window.

But if I open the query in display mode, I can save it to a new name and it does that without calculating it, which is what I needed.